# Editar un datos String extraido desde SQL SERVER en Java

Tags: java, sql-server, json, spring-boot, spring

Extraje un dato de tipo string de una base de datos SQL, el campo llamado "IdCuerpo" tiene como valor

{La creación de los archivos de la fecha "fecha" se realizó de forma exitosa, en la ruta: "ruta"}

lo que quiero saber es como insertar 2 variables una es fecha en el lugar de "fecha" y ruta en el lugar de "ruta" . todo esto desde Java.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código donde estás intentando hacer ésto? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).